# DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration()); sometimes returns null

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have a MR job that reads data from an HBase table. The mapper of this job `MyMapper` extends `TableMapper`.

I also have a method that receives an instance of Configuration.
I call it from within the `setup()` of `MyMapper`:

```
Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();  
foo(conf);
```

From within `foo`, I call `DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf)`.

`foo` works fine in another MR job, only there the mapper extends the class `Mapper`. This job is also written with `mapreduce` API.
However in `MyMapper` it does not work.

I also tried:

```
Configuration conf = (JobConf) context.getConfiguration();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2568962

Comment: what is the comment about? is that the same as your code? is the answer valid for your question? if not, please add the `setup`, `foo` and `main` methods to your question.